# Keep slideDown() menu open after the page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I want to keep my slide down menu open even after the page is refreshed. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").click(function (e) {

        $("#box").slideDown(1000);

    });
});
```

Comment: Is it always loading open or only when they have opened it and refreshed page?

Answer (score 1):

If it always loads open just set your CSS to display it initially. No code needed! If you want to only load it open after they have loaded the page, opened it and then refreshed you can use sessionStorage to save the state. Note this will only work as long as they don't close the browser window/tab. Once they do it will reset itself.

As another note if the scenario is the latter there are other ways to pass that current state but this is one option.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/d38bdsuh/

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass"></div>
<button id="mybutton">open</button>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',
    function () {
        $('.someClass').slideDown(1000);
        sessionStorage.setItem('opened', 'true');
        alert('click run button now');
    }
);

var opened = sessionStorage.getItem('opened');
if (opened == 'true') {
    $('.someClass').css('display', 'block');
}
```